# 404 error configaration with pre compilied jsp not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am trying to configure 404 error page in my web.xml for my spring 2.4 application which contains pre complied JSp's only. But its  not working, i have tried it in many combinations and permutations. I have tried exceptionhandler in spring too for the 404 exception but noneof them worked.below is the code, can someone let me know where i went wrong.

I am using tomcat server

```
<error-page> 
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/jsp/error/error_jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: where does your error_.jsp locate?

Comment: why would you do this?

Comment: @I WISH for customised error pages

Answer (score 1):

You are using the location of the class file which is not correct. Use the URL of the compiled JSP (which I'm guessing is something like /jsp/error.jsp - look in your sevrlet mappings to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

JSPs are compiled into servlets and dynamically added as such to a web application.

As you have skipped the JSP processing you need to add org.apache.jsp.jsp.error.error_jsp.class as a servlet to your web.xml file.

You can then use the servlet context as the error-page location.

Comment: we already have the org.apache.jsp.jsp.error.error_jsp.class entry in the web.xml